# Why does the error "filename does not exist" come up?

Tags: c#, variables

I am trying to make a button that splits a video into several frames, but I can't figure out why filename still has an error.
Am I not defining it in OpenFileDialog?
Here is the code.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
        string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }

        FilgraphManager filgraphManager = new FilgraphManager();
        filgraphManager.RenderFile(fileName);
        IBasicVideo bv = (IBasicVideo)filgraphManager;
        int vx, vy;
        bv.GetVideoSize(out vx, out vy);
        var scale = 100F / (float)vx; //100Fのところに出力画像の長辺の長さを入れる
        var w = (int)(scale * vx);
        var h = (int)(scale * vy);

        var md = (IMediaDet)new MediaDet();
        md.Filename = fileName;
        md.CurrentStream = 0;
        string name = @"hoge.bmp";
        md.WriteBitmapBits(5.0d, w, h, name);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong in defining filename1? How do it fix it?

Comment: `string filename1 = openFileDialog1.FileName`?

Comment: I changed it to that, but still filgraphManager.RenderFile(fileName); and md.Filename = fileName; have errors. (Sorry, I meant to type fileName instead of filename1).

Comment: where is filename1 in the code?

Comment: string filename;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
         {
        fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

Comment: Maybe the input of showDialog it is different from DialogResult.OK, and it never set fileName?

Answer (score 1):

In comments I am having trouble to write code. You have to define filename's type outside if block:

```
string fileName="";
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
        fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks that got the error from md.Filename = fileName; cleared but still theres now a different error for filgraphManager.RenderFile(fileName);, saying "use of unassigned local variable ".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that fileName was only assigned inside the if statement.
This solved it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() ==      System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;


            FilgraphManager filgraphManager = new FilgraphManager();
            filgraphManager.RenderFile(fileName);
            IBasicVideo bv = (IBasicVideo)filgraphManager;
            int vx, vy;
            bv.GetVideoSize(out vx, out vy);
            var scale = 100F / (float)vx; //100Fのところに出力画像の長辺の長さを入れる
            var w = (int)(scale * vx);
            var h = (int)(scale * vy);

            var md = (IMediaDet)new MediaDet();
            md.Filename = fileName;
            md.CurrentStream = 0;
            string name = @"hoge.bmp";
            md.WriteBitmapBits(5.0d, w, h, name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a variable in scope from somewhere else called filename which you then overwrite with the output from the dialog box here... but...

```
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
    string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    }

    FilgraphManager filgraphManager = new FilgraphManager();
    filgraphManager.RenderFile(fileName);
```

So in that RenderFile call the filename is probably still empty.